# Irfanview: batch conversion systematically resizing

Tags: windows, batch, troubleshooting, resizing, irfanview

I've just installed a fresh version of irfanview to convert a large number of images to .PNG, but the output resolution won't budge from 1920x1280. Input files are 8392x5620 .RW2, all plugins installed. So far I've attempted, individually and in combination:

- disabling resizing altogether
- enabling optipng
- forcing resize to 8392x5620 (takes a long time to process, outputs a blurry upscaled mess)
- set new size as percentage of original: 100%
- "this is the minimal size"
- "don't shrink bigger images"
- looking for anything affecting output res in properties/settings
- wiping with Revo and reinstalling

I'm at a loss, all of these still output low res images. Has anyone seen this before? It hasn't happened on any of my previous devices.

Comment: Are you ready to change the software?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, [IrfanView is not alone in having issues with the proprietary RW2 format](https://github.com/darktable-org/rawspeed/issues/126), especially for the very high resolution mode. Both [darktable](https://www.darktable.org/) and [Raw Therapee](https://www.rawtherapee.com/) had problems in the past, but are worth trying. All three, IrfanView, darktable, and Raw Therapee, are *excellent* applications, in my opinion, rivaling many commercial products, but each has some limitations.

However, Panasonic had partnered with [ISL](https://silkypix.isl.co.jp/en/download/) to handle the proprietary RW2 format, and included a licensed version of [SILKYPIX Developer Studio SE](https://www.isl.co.jp/SILKYPIX/english/p/support/download/) with purchase of a camera. It includes [batch "development" operations](http://www.silkypix.us/silkypix-features/silkypix-batch-develop) (i.e., format conversion). If you do not have a license through Panasonic, you can download and use the app for 30 days.